# Void not allowed here

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I'm trying to work out a way of creating a JTextfield dynamically without assigning it to a variable.

```
panel.add(new JTextField("hello"));
```

The code above works just fine, but when I try and manipulate like below the compiler says Void not allowed here. I'm a beginner and I know this is probably something simple, please help me out.

```
panel.add(new JTextField("hello").setForeground(Color.yellow));
```

Comment: _creating a JTextfield dynamically without assigning it to a variable._ Why do you try to avoid that?

Comment: The number of textfields will vary depending on the game load.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get why this would be a problem. Local variables are local to a method or constructor and then discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define your own *constructor*, so that you can chain those calls together, although I don't know if it's worth the trouble, just to avoid a variable.

```
private JTextField newColoredTextField(String s, Color c) {
    JTextField tf = new JTextField(s);
    tf.setForeground(c);
    return tf;
}
```

You may then use it like so:

```
panel.add(newColoredTextField("hello", Color.yellow));
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I needed to do. Thank you very much Sir afsantos.

Answer (score 3):

`setForeground` returns `void`. It modifies the `JTextField` instead of returning a new one.

Do it this way might help:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField("hello");
field.setForeground(Color.yellow);
panel.add(field);
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not the relevant doc. This one one refers to DefaultTableCellRenderer and not JComponent. Moreover, you refer to Java 6 and not Java 7.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thanks, that's too careless.

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain the constructor and the call to setForeground together. The return value of the statement will be the return value of the last method call, which is `void`.

Instead, you need to instantiate the field, modify it, then add it:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField("hello");
field.setForeground(Color.yellow);

panel.add(field);
```